# Guice submodules prevent inheriting bindings

Tags: java, inheritance, module, overriding, guice

I would like to accomplish the following without introducing annotations or using string key names, is it possible using `Guice`? Also, introducing a third private module for `MyService` and its `ExecutorService` binding is less than ideal, because I'd like the ExecutorService to be a singleton for the entire app, injected not just in `MyService`, but potentially other classes, say `MyOtherService` for example.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyAppModule());
    final MyService service = injector.getInstance(MyService.class);
    service.printInternals();
    // Ideally this would print something like:
    // My Executor: ExecutorImplClass@1
    // Red Executor: ExecutorImplClass@2
    // Blue Executor: ExecutorImplClass@3
  }
}

public class MyAppModule extends PrivateModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    install(new RedModule());
    install(new BlueModule());
    bind(ExecutorService.class).toInstance(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
    bind(MyService.class).to(MyServiceImpl.class);
    expose(MyService.class);
  }
}

public class BlueModule extends PrivateModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(ExecutorService.class).toInstance(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
    bind(BlueService.class).to(BlueServiceImpl.class);
    expose(BlueService.class);
  }
}

public interface BlueService {
  void printInternals();
}

class BlueServiceImpl implements BlueService {
  private final ExecutorService executor;

  @Inject
  BlueServiceImpl(final ExecutorService executor) {
    this.executor = executor;
  }

  @Override
  public void printInternals() {
    System.out.println("Blue Executor: " + executor);
  }
}
```

`RedModule, RedService and RedServiceImpl` all mirror their respective `Blue*` classes.

Finally `MyService`, which uses the `Red` and `Blue Services` as well as it's own `ExecutorService`:

```
class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
  private final ExecutorService executor;
  private final RedService red;
  private final BlueService blue;

  @Inject
  MyServiceImpl(final ExecutorService executor, final RedService red, final BlueService blue) {
    this.executor = executor;
    this.red = red;
    this.blue = blue;
  }

  @Override
  public void printInternals() {
    System.out.println("My Executor: " + executor);
    red.printInternals();
    blue.printInternals();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TL;DR: Isolate the `Blue` and `Red` Modules to their own injectors and create providers in your `App's` module which call the `getInstance()` method of the injectors to retrieve the services your app needs.

Now for how I came to the solution:

Private Modules can get you most of the way there, see [my experimentation](https://gist.github.com/mmadson/5468416).

But...

Let's say I'm developing an application which uses a service to do something totally awesome.

```
public class MyAppModule extends PrivateModule {
  bind(AwesomeService.class).to(AwesomeServiceImpl.class);
  expose(AwesomeService.class);
}
```

Now the particular implementation of my `AwesomeService` needs a few things to be as awesome as it is:

```
class AwesomeServiceImpl implements AwesomeService {
  @Inject
  AwesomeServiceImpl(BlueService blue, RedService red, ExecutorService executor) { ... }
}
```

It just so happens that some upstanding Internet denizen has created a standalone jar with Guice modules that provide both `Red` and `Blue` Services. So I'll add the jar to my classpath and modify `MyAppModule` so that my `AwesomeService` can use the third party `Red` and `Blue` Services:

```
public class MyAppModule extends PrivateModule {
  install(new RedModule());
  install(new BlueModule());
  bind(AwesomeService.class).to(AwesomeServiceImpl.class);
  expose(AwesomeService.class);
}
```

I also need an `ExecutorService` for my `AwesomeService`, so I'll go ahead and bind to an explicit instance for now:

```
public class MyAppModule extends PrivateModule {
  install(new RedModule());
  install(new BlueModule());
  bind(ExecutorService.class).toInstance(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
  bind(AwesomeService.class).to(AwesomeServiceImpl.class);
  expose(AwesomeService.class);
}
```

Ah, but damn, apparently my good Internet friend decided to expose not only the `RedService` and `BlueService` bindings that my `AwesomeService` needs, but also an `ExecutorService` that I don't want:

```
public final class BlueModule extends PrivateModule {
  bind(ExecutorService.class).toInstance(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
  bind(BlueService.class).to(BlueServiceImpl.class);

  expose(ExecutorService.class);
  expose(BlueService.class);
}

public final class RedModule extends PrivateModule {
  bind(ExecutorService.class).toInstance(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
  bind(RedService.class).to(RedServiceImpl.class);

  expose(ExecutorService.class);
  expose(RedService.class);
}
```

No problem, I'll just wrap his modules in a private module and expose only the services I care about:

```
public class MyAppModule extends PrivateModule {
  install(new PrivateModule() {
    install(new RedModule());
    expose(RedService.class);
  });
  install(new PrivateModule() { 
    install(new BlueModule());
    expose(BlueService.class);
  });
  bind(ExecutorService.class).toInstance(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
  bind(AwesomeService.class).to(AwesomeServiceImpl.class);
  expose(AwesomeService.class);
}
```

Ahh, but damn again, my `ExecutorService` binding is inherited by my private wrapper modules and is conflicting with the internal bindings defined in the `RedModule` and `BlueModule`. I guess I could annotate or Name my `ExecutorService` in my `AwesomeService` constructor, but what if I want that `ExecutorService` to be a singleton shared all over my app, by 20, 30 or 40 different services. I'll have to pollute all my `ExecutorService` injections with this annotation.

Or I suppose I could do some trickery, staggering the bindings and hiding the `ExecutorService` so it doesn't conflict with the `ExecutorService` that `RedModule` and `BlueModule` create, but this just seems wrong:

```
public class MyAppModule extends PrivateModule {
  install(new PrivateModule() {
    install(new RedModule());
    expose(RedService.class);
  });
  install(new PrivateModule() { 
    install(new BlueModule());
    expose(BlueService.class);
  });

  final Module myAppExecutorService = new PrivateModule() {
    bind(ExecutorService.class).toInstance(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());  
    expose(ExecutorService.class);
  };
  install(new PrivateModule() {
    install(myAppExecutorService);
    bind(AwesomeService.class).to(AwesomeServiceImpl.class);
    expose(AwesomeService.class);
  });  
  expose(AwesomeService.class);
}
```

There must be a better way... and there is... Injectors!

```
public class MyAppModule extends PrivateModule {
  private static final Injector blueInjector = Guice.createInjector(new BlueModule());
  private static final Injector redInjector = Guice.createInjector(new RedModule());

  @Override
  protected void configure()
  {
    bind(ExecutorService.class).toInstance(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
    bind(MyService.class).to(MyServiceImpl.class);
    bind(MyOtherService.class).to(MyOtherServiceImpl.class);
    expose(MyService.class);
    expose(MyOtherService.class);
  }

  @Provides
  RedService getRedService()
  {
    return redInjector.getInstance(RedService.class);
  }

  @Provides
  BlueService getBlueService()
  {
    return blueInjector.getInstance(BlueService.class);
  }
}
```

Now the `ExecutorService` that is bound and exposed in both the `BlueModule` and `RedModule` won't pollute my `AwesomeService's` `ExecutorService`, yet I can still get my hands on those juicy `BlueService` and `RedService` classes I so desperately want.

Hopefully this saves someone else some time in the future!

Comment: Be aware that using Injectors instead of modules will prevent your from overriding them. https://github.com/google/guice/issues/347